# extracting data between span tags with BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract data between span tags. Here is a sample of html code:

```
<p>
    <span class="html-italic">3-Acetyl-</span>
    <span class="html-italic">(4-acetyl-5-(β</span>
    "-"
    <span class="html-italic">naphtyl)-4,5-dihydro-1,3,4-oxodiazol-2-yl)methoxy)-2H-chromen-2-one</span>
     "("
    <b>5b</b>
</p>
```

I need to get a full name:

`3-Acetyl-4-acetyl-5-(β-naphtyl)-4,5-dihydro-1,3,4-oxodiazol-2-yl)methoxy)-2H-chromen-2-one` (without 5b). I don't know how to extract '-' between the second and the third span tags. Also, a total number of span tags may vary and '-' can be between any span tags. The code I wrote gives me only: 3-Acetyl-4-acetyl-5-(β. Here is a part of my code:

```
p = soup.find("p")
name = ""
for child in p.children:
    if child.name == "span":
        name += child.text
print name
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

```
>>> ''.join(i.text for i in soup.select('p > span'))
'3-Acetyl-(4-acetyl-5-(βnaphtyl)-4,5-dihydro-1,3,4-oxodiazol-2-yl)methoxy)-2H-chromen-2-one'
```

Comment: This misses the `"-"` outside the spans (should be β-naphtyl).

Answer (score 2):

you can just do something like

```
p = soup.find("p")
name = ""
for child in p.children:
    if child.name == "span":
        name += child.text
    elif child.name is 'None':
        name += child.string.rstrip("\"\n ").lstrip("\"\n ")
print name
```

Comment: you might also have to strip the quotation marks from "-" and "(". use rstrip and lstrip

Comment: you can do that is noting in that

Answer (score 2):

You can use BeautifulSoup's `.findAll(text=True)` to get all text inside the element, including outside the spans. This returns a list of text parts, which need to be stripped of whitespace and quotation marks. I'm not sure what rule you're using to exclude the last `"("5b` but maybe it's as easy as slicing the list:

```
parts = soup.find("p").findAll(text=True)
name = ''.join(p.strip(string.whitespace + '"') for p in parts[:-3])
```

Result:

```
u'3-Acetyl-(4-acetyl-5-(β-naphtyl)-4,5-dihydro-1,3,4-oxodiazol-2-yl)methoxy)-2H-chromen-2-one'
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
name=""
for x in soup.find('p'):
    try:
        if x.name == 'span':
            name += x.get_text()
    except:pass
print name
```

output:

```
3-Acetyl-(4-acetyl-5-(Î˛naphtyl)-4,5-dihydro-1,3,4-oxodiazol-2-yl)methoxy)-2H-chromen-2-one
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like one-liners, you can do something like:

```
(your_item.find("p", {"attr": "value"})).find("span").get_text()
```